# How can I automatically assign values to the field based upon the checkbox selected by the user in flows?

Tags: automation, flow-builder, flowscreen, flow-screen-component

I am trying a lot to assign template values based upon checkbox list choice by the user. Unfortunately, it is working but not completing addressing the feature I need.

For example, if user chooses the choice apex class and trigger, then the cost for apex class and trigger is automatically added and multiplied with template values (number of people required to perform the task).

[image: output]
[image]

This is happening because I have created a decision box that checks the choices and sums up the assigned template values for each and every checkbox category.

[image]

But what if the user creates a new template. This should be automatically be added to the values, rather than checking the decision box each and every time. Can anyone help me with the situation? I tried to google the solution, but couldn't get the right solution, i.e. instead of checking decision box, the values should be summed up automatically based upon the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the similar steps mentioned in https://www.sfdcpanther.com/create-roll-up-summary-field-using-flow-builder-in-salesforce/. It worked.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged because the link tends to change over time (or the content is removed). You should [edit] your question to include the important parts of the solution here on SFSE.